# How to pass select option label field's value or selected text to a functions argument

Tags: jquery, angularjs, ng-options, angularjs-ng-options, angularjs-ng-change

My requirement is to get the chosen option and update a div. I've simulated my requirement in the code below.

I'm supposed to let user choose only the end of the months between startDate and endDate (I've done this part in the code below). But I couldn't update the  with the chosen date. I could only access the "value" attribute in the  Not the label or text.

[http://jsfiddle.net/priyaa2002/xpcbounr/3/](http://codepen.io/hganesan/pen/c54285debfaeb47e22bec0078ecbcc2a)

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
   <div ng-controller="DateCtrl">
      <div class="edit__table__field"><p>{{myEnrollment.coverageEndDate}}</p></div>
         <select ng-model="myEnrollment.coverageEndDate" ng-options="value as coverageEndDate for (value, coverageEndDate) in
        terminationDates"
        ng-change="newTerminationDate(myEnrollment.coverageEndDate)" >
                <option value="">Select your new Termination Date</option>
        </select>
   </div>
</div>
```

## JS

```
angular.module('myApp', [])
  .controller('DateCtrl', function($scope){
  $scope.myEnrollment = {
    coverageStartDate: '01/01/2016',
    coverageEndDate: '06/01/2016'
  };

    var startDate = new Date ($scope.myEnrollment.coverageStartDate);
    var endDate = new Date ($scope.myEnrollment.coverageEndDate);

    var startMonth = startDate.getMonth();
    var endMonth = endDate.getMonth();
    var year = endDate.getFullYear();

  function convertDate(date) {
    var parts = date.toString().split(" ");
    var months = {
      Jan: "01",
      Feb: "02",
      Mar: "03",
      Apr: "04",
      May: "05",
      Jun: "06",
      Jul: "07",
      Aug: "08",
      Sep: "09",
      Oct: "10",
      Nov: "11",
      Dec: "12"
    };
    return months[parts[1]]+"/"+parts[2]+"/"+parts[3];
};


  var pickDates = endMonth - startMonth;
$scope.terminationDates = [];
for (var i=0; i < pickDates; i++){
      var lastDay = new Date(year, i + 1, 0);
        var formatedDate = convertDate(lastDay);
        $scope.terminationDates.push(formatedDate); 
}
$scope.newTerminationDate = function(coverageDate)  {
    $scope.myEnrollment.coverageDate = "hello";
}

});
```

Comment: Your binded array to the select option does not contain '06/01/2016' which is passed to your ng-model. That is why nothing is selected by default

Comment: This is what your array contains ["01/31/2016","02/29/2016","03/31/2016","04/30/2016","05/31/2016"]

Comment: 06/01/2016 is the start date. Thats already there. User can edit endDate, for which they can choose only the end of month between startdate and end date

Comment: The rule is ng-model value must be there in the binded array for it to be preselected

Comment: i didn't get what you are saying

Comment: Your ng-model = 06/01/2016 whereas your array $scope.terminationDates is ["01/31/2016","02/29/2016","03/31/2016","04/30/2016","05/31/2016"] which does not contain value passed to ng-model. Hence nothing is selected

Comment: its getting selected and printing the {0,1,2,3,4} which is nothing but the value="" attributes value in <option>. If you inspect the code.. you can see

Comment: I think you are not getting what I am trying to explain. What exactly is the problem then?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118732/discussion-between-dragonfly-and-rahul-arora).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
 <select ng-model="myEnrollment.coverageEndDate" ng-options="value as value for value in terminationDates" ng-change="newTerminationDate(myEnrollment.coverageEndDate)" >
        <option value="">Select your new Termination Date</option>
 </select>
```

Hope it helps!